# Integrals from Brasilian Math Olympiad 2019

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

The following integrals are the Brasilian Mathematical Olympiad in 2019.

Show that $\displaystyle\int_1^2\frac{e^x(x-1)}{x(x+e^x)}\,dx=\ln\left(\frac{2+e^2}{2+2e}\right)$ and  $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin(2x)}{1+\cos(2x)^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$.

I tried to use traditional methods, but these integrals are very difficult. Has someone any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As a "test-taker's answer" for the first one, the fact that $F(2) - F(1) = \ln \left(\frac{2 + e^2}{2 + 2e}\right)$ is a big hint that $F(x)$ is probably $\ln \left(\frac{x + e^x}{x + xe}\right)$ (such that $F(2) = \ln \left(\frac{2 + e^2}{2 + 2e}\right)$ and $F(1) = 0$); and it's straightforward to confirm that that is in fact the case, by taking its derivative, $F^\prime(x) = \frac{e^x(x-1)}{x(x+e^x)}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\int_1^2\frac{e^x(x-1)}{x(x+e^x)}dx=\int_1^2 \frac{e^x\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{1+\frac{e^x}{x}}dx=\ln\left(1+\frac{e^x}{x}\right)\bigg|_1^2 =\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{e^2}{2}}{1+e}\right)$$

---

For the second one, let $\frac{\pi}{2}-x=t$ to get:
$$\mathcal J=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin(2x)}{1+\cos^2(2x)}dx=\int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)\sin(2t)}{1+\cos^2(2t)}(-dt)\overset{t=x}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\sin(2x)}{1+\cos^2(2x)}dx$$
Now add them up to get:
$$2\mathcal J=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(2x)}{1+\cos^2(2x)}dx\Rightarrow \mathcal J=-\frac{\pi}{8}\arctan(\cos(2x))\bigg|_0^\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$$

Comment: Your last integral has the wrong bounds of integration after substitution.  Just take out the negative.

Comment: If $x\to0$ in $\frac{\pi}2-x=t$, then what is $t\to$?

Comment: @AndrewChin Are you overlooking $dt=-dx$?

Comment: Oh that's what I overlooked

Answer (score 4):

For the second integral, use $\int_a^bf(x) = \int_a^bf(a+b-x)$ and add these together to get $I =$$ \int_0^\frac\pi2 {\frac \pi4\sin(2x)\over1+\cos(2x)^2}$. Substituting with $\cos(2x) = t$ gives the solution easily.

Comment: this answer would be a lot more impressive if it was written by a dog

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\int \frac {2\sin (2x)}{1+\cos^2(2x)}dx=-\arctan (\cos(2x))$$ (you can show this by substitution)